# How to test hibernate lifecycle observers?

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing

I'm having problems whilst trying to test a JPA entity lifecycle observer, registered as `POST_COMMIT_INSERT`

Because my observer is a spring bean, I wire it into the entity manager as follows:

```
private void configureHibernateHooks(HistoricEventListener<?> listener) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();

    EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory).getServiceRegistry().getService(
            EventListenerRegistry.class);

    if (listener instanceof PostInsertEventListener)
    {
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_INSERT).appendListener((PostInsertEventListener) listener);
    }
}

SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

My test is annotated as `@Transactional`.  Therefore, as I understand it, each test runs within it's own transaction.  This is preventing my observer method from being invoked, as the transaction doesn't commit during my test, so the `POST_COMMIT_XXX` listeners are never observed.

I've tried injecting the `EntityManager` and manually commiting transactions, but that resulted in exceptions.

What's an appropriate strategy for testing these?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @Rollback(false) annotation on a test method to direct spring to commit the transaction instead of rolling it back.

Even triggering an entityManger.flush() should suffice. I don't think the event triggering is associated with the commit of the transaction (the name might be misleading).

Comment: Yeah, I'd considered that.  I have a working version now which uses `@TransactionConfiguration(rollback=false)`, and `@AfterTransaction`.  However, I'm hoping for a cleaner alternative, as this leaves the db messy after the test finishes (whereas all our other tests clean up via the transaction).

Comment: What about the entityManager.flush() - did you try that?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, and the callback method isn't invoked until after the test has completed, which is too late (as I miss my opportunity for asserts)